# Locating an element in Selenium with a custom value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with a web page that needs some automation and having trouble interacting with certain elements due to their structure.  Brief example:

```
<ul>
<li data-title="Search" data-action="search">
<li class="disabled" data-title="Ticket Grid" data-action="ticket-grid">
<li data-title="Create Ticket" data-action="create">
<li data-title="Settings" data-action="settings">
</ul>
```

I am aware of all the locator strategies like id and name listed here:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

However, is there a way to specify finding something by a custom value like in this example "data-title"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS to select any attribute, this is what the formula looks like:

```
element[attribute(*|^|$|~)='value']
```

Per your example, it would be:

```
li[data-title='Ticket Grid']
```

(source http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best way!

Comment: @GatesOfDelirium: Please mark it as answer and/or upvote it, if this has helped you out. This will help others who are facing the similar problem.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple possibilities it is also worth knowing the following option

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

driver = Firefox()
driver.get(<your_html>)

li_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for li in li_list:
    if li.get_attribute('data-title') == '<wanted_value>':
        <do_your_thing>
```

Comment: Good for multiple possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
"//li[@data-title='Ticket Grid']"
```

Comment: This works, but it seems like the CSS approach might handle deeper nested elements better.